# Whether it is the pigeonhole principle?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I had a question, and I am just wondering if it is a question that involves combinations/permutations or the pigeonhole principle.

In a class are $20$ students. What is the probability that at least three of these students have thee same zodiac sign (there are 12 zodiac signs in total)?

I was seeing if anyone would like to explain to me, on how to determine if a question involves combination/permutation or the pigeonhole principle?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be good that you include your own thoughts on this problem.

Comment: The pigeonhole principle tells you that at least two students must have the same zodiac sign, since there are more than $12$ students. It even tells you that if there are *not* $3$ students with the same sign, then there must be $8$ signs with two students each. It won’t tell you much of anything about probabilities, however.

Comment: If we make appropriate randomness assumptions, it is a probability problem, solvable by standard counting methods.

Answer (score 0):

Pigeonhole and combination both will be used here. To find answer one would like to discard the case when 1) all are of different sign & 2) some sign has two people and no sign has 3 or more.
Pigeonhole says case 1) is not possible and to count possibilities of case 2) one needs combination.